# Update Query with annotation using Spring and MongoRepository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-repositories

I am using the latest version of Spring Boot and Spring Data MongoRepository. I have written a custom repository interface

```
    public interface CompanyRepository extends MongoRepository<Company, String>{

    @Query(value = "{ 'employer.userId' : ?0 }")
    Company findByCompanyUserUserId(String userId);
}
```

In the same way i want to use @Query annotation for updating a particular field. can someone suggest me?

Comment: Use MongoTemplate for update operations. Query is for queries.

Comment: Yes Sagar, I am already using MongoTemplate, but i want to use annotation to reduce writing lot of code, any better solution ?

Comment: Like I said query means read only operation. There are no updates and is not possible.

Comment: There is no @update implementation in spring data mongo.

Answer (score 4):

Create an annotation like this:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface MongoUpdate {

String find() default "{}";

String update() default "{}";

String collection();

boolean multi() default false;
}
```

And an aspect like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class MongoUpdateAspect {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoUpdateAspect.class);

@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Pointcut("@annotation(com.ofb.commons.aop.common.MongoUpdate)")
public void pointCut() {
}

@Around("com.ofb.commons.aspect.MongoUpdateAspect.pointCut() && @annotation(mongoUpdate)")
public Object applyQueryUpdate(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MongoUpdate mongoUpdate) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

    String findQuery = mongoUpdate.find();
    String updateQuery = mongoUpdate.update();
    String collection = mongoUpdate.collection();
    boolean multiUpdate = mongoUpdate.multi();

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (args[i] instanceof Collection) {
            Collection collection1 = (Collection) args[i];
            String replaceStr = (String) collection1.stream().map(object -> {
                if (object instanceof Number) {
                    return object.toString();
                } else {
                    return String.format("\"%s\"", object.toString());
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            findQuery = findQuery.replace(String.format("?%s", i), replaceStr);
            updateQuery = updateQuery.replace(String.format("?%s", i), replaceStr);
        } else if (args[i] instanceof Object[]) {
            Object[] objects = (Object[]) args[i];
            String replaceStr = Arrays.stream(objects).map(object -> {
                if (object instanceof Number) {
                    return object.toString();
                } else {
                    return String.format("\"%s\"", object.toString());
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            findQuery = findQuery.replace(String.format("?%s", i), replaceStr);
            updateQuery = updateQuery.replace(String.format("?%s", i), replaceStr);
        } else {
            if (args[i] instanceof Number) {
                findQuery = findQuery.replace(String.format("?%s", i), args[i].toString());
                updateQuery.replace(String.format("?%s", i), args[i].toString());
            } else {
                findQuery = findQuery.replace(String.format("?%s", i), String.format("\"%s\"", args[i].toString()));
                updateQuery =
                    updateQuery.replace(String.format("?%s", i), String.format("\"%s\"", args[i].toString()));
            }
        }
    }

    Query query = new BasicQuery(findQuery);
    Update update = new BasicUpdate(updateQuery);

    if (multiUpdate) {
        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, collection);
    } else {
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, collection);
    }
    return null;
   }
}
```

This will not work in MongoRepository implemented interfaces but you can create an empty bodied method in your service layer

```
@MongoUpdate(find = {}, update = "{$push : {'offFeatures' : ?0}}", collection = "userPreference", multi = true)
public void offFeatures(String feature) {

}
```

Comment: This is a great example of abstracting out underlying complex implementation and presenting user with an easy to use user interface. 
Would be great if this gets adopted by spring data.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reasonable question. Assuming that you're using the org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository class, can you not simply use the insert(..) or save(..) methods for what you need?

[API docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html)